# Hive QL retrieve max value

Tags: sql, hiveql

I am trying to use Hive QL to retrieve data from the database. I have 2 columns start_time having the starting time and time_stamp which is recorded for each of the works done starting from 'Start_time'

```
JOB         start_time              work_done             time_stamp
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
JOB_A     2021/12/29 11:00:00       work_A            2021/12/29 11:00:00
JOB_A     2021/12/29 11:00:00       work_A            2021/12/29 11:20:00
JOB_A     2021/12/29 11:00:00       work_B            2021/12/29 11:45:00
JOB_B     2021/12/29 11:00:00       work_A            2021/12/29 12:00:00
JOB_B     2021/12/29 11:00:00       work_A            2021/12/29 12:15:00
JOB_B     2021/12/29 11:00:00       work_B            2021/12/29 12:30:00
```

What I want is the start_time of JOB_A and the time_stamp where JOB_A and JOB_B ends

```
JOB         start_time                     time_stamp
------------------------------------------------------------
JOB_A     2021/12/29 11:00:00            2021/12/29 11:45:00
JOB_B     2021/12/29 11:00:00            2021/12/29 12:30:00
```

I tried to use

```
select 
JOB,
start_time,
max(time_stamp)
from table_1
```

I am still getting the same table as my output

Comment: HiveQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Please provide your desired results.

Comment: I suggest researching `group by`.

Comment: Okay let me check on it thanks Dale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select c.JOB, max(c.time_stamp) from test1229 c
join (select * from test1229) d on d.JOB = c.JOB where c.time_stamp > d.time_stamp group by c.JOB

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a group-by clause in your select

```
select 
JOB,
start_time,
max(time_stamp)
from table_1
group by JOB, start_time
```

this way, you get for each distinct pair of JOB/Start_time the max(time_stamp) from your records.

Keep in mind that, if JOB_A will start again at another start_time, there will be a second row with JOB_A and its respective new start_time and time_stamp values.